# Powershell to non-domain machine

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication

I'm writing a small script that needs at one point to connect to a machine that is not a domain member. The machine the script is run from will always be a domain member.

I've found that using the following works

```
cd WSMan:\localhost\Client    
Set-Item .\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force
```

but I'm looking for an alternative because to use the above commands powershell has to be "run as administrator" and it is only effective during that PS session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing trustedhosts requires local admin priveliges (and is a one-time operation), but the subsequent connection(s) to the non-domain computer do not.

Comment: Strange when I type Enter-pssession <servername> I get an error that contains "The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication" which I believed was still a trusted hosts issue. However if I use Enter-pssession -name <servername> I get a similar error but no mention of Kerberos.